# Перевод desktop-приложения в апплет

Tags: applet, java

Скажите, а вот, например, у меня уже есть готовая программа, можно ли (и как) создать апплет, реализующий то же самое, что и программа? Или придется создавать "чистый" апплет и в нем переписывать эту программу?

Answer (score 3):

Боюсь, что проще сделать совсем наоборот. Весь код программы поместить в апплет. Добавить к нему метод `main` примерно следующего содержания:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame ("using applet");
f.add( new CustomApplet() );
...

f.setVisible(true);
```

Метод `main` будет использоватся только в режиме "прогрммы". т.е у апплета совсем другой entry-point

Answer (score 0):

Странный вопрос. Смотря что за программа, что Вы хотите получить. Скорее всего, можно будет использовать какие-то части, какие-то классы и т.д. Но кое-что придется переписать или дописать, разумеется.

Comment: MVC, extend JFrame заменить на extend Applet, удалить лишние методы  и если там что-то не слишком сложное, в плане ГУИ, то должно работать

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй покопаться в строну java web start.   [java web start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/developing.html)

Если у тебя есть возможность перевести свой проект в среду netbeans, то там есть автоматизация создания JWS варианта приложения.